# How to create a desktop icon to launch a mobile application using Sencha Touch 2?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I coded a mobile application using sencha touch 2 Framework.
I didn't find any tutorial that explains clearly how to create a desktop icon to launch the application from my list of application. Does anyone can help me, please ?
Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: be more clear in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're asking about how to get the application running from your desktop or from your device.

---

I typically run my application on a desktop for testing from chrome with something like file:///path/to/my/sencha/index.html.

Another option is to host it from a webserver like [lampp/xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html). There are many options for webservers.

---

If your are trying to get it onto a device see the [Sencha Cmd native packaging docs.](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/guide/native_packaging)

Another option here is to use [Phonegap/Cordova](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/index.html) to package a native app.

If you provide more clarification I can provide more specifics, hope this helps!

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your answer. I'm going to try this. Bye.